# Custom iOS UIDatepicker using UIAppearance

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uidatepicker, uiappearance

[UNIQLO's new alarm app](http://www.uniqlo.com/wakeup/en/pc/) has a custom `UIDatePicker`:

[image: custom]

And I want to create my own custom `UIDatePicker`.

I tried to change the appearance of the DatePicker, but looking for `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` in the `UIDatePicker` returns *nothing*.

Meaning that its not possible to change any values, as per the docs:

> [To support appearance customization, a class must conform to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol and relevant accessor methods must be marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance)

How can change my `UIDatePicker`'s appearance?

Comment: please excuse the HUGE image..

Comment: you want only 2 component in UIDatePicker or just need that white font of text as a customization?

Comment: Customising as much as I can: Font, colour, everything.

Comment: Please take a look I have customized the inner-view of picker, you can change the code as per requirement.

Comment: are you getting any issue in customizing the pickers' content with the method I go ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The API does not provide a way to do this.
You can make a pretty convincing replica yourself using a UIPickerView rather than using UIDatePicker.

As the UIDatePicker or UIPickerView don't have the UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR and even you can't change UIDatePicker contents' appearance as its UIControl and not having any delegate so it has its native appearance whereas in case of UIPickerView you can change its contents' appearance similar as in UITableView.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPicker Delegate & DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 100;
}
//- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:  (NSInteger)component {
     //    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row];
//}
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

      UILabel *label= [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)] autorelease];
      [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
      [label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
      [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:40.0]];
      [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row]];

      return label;
}
```

[image]

Check this out.

Answer (score 4):

add this method in your implementation file

```
-(UIView *)pickerViews{

    return ([datePicker.subviews objectAtIndex:0]);
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self pickerViews].subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@ --- > %i",obj, idx);
    }];
}
```

when you run your app it will display all the subviews of the datePicker on your console, just choose any index and modify them one by one

modify the viewDidLoad and insert this code

```
UIView *background = (UIView *)[[self pickerViews].subviews objectAtIndex:0];
background.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *wheel2 = (UIView *)[[self pickerViews].subviews objectAtIndex:4];
wheel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIView *wheel3 = (UIView *)[[self pickerViews].subviews objectAtIndex:11];
wheel3.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In this case i change the background color of index "0", "4", "11"

Answer (score 3):

With iOS 5 the [UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) protocol was introduced, which lets you customize several UI elements. UIDatePicker happens to conform this protocol, so that is probably the easiest way to do this. That is, if you're willing to support only iOS 5 users. Matthew's option would probably the next best thing, which should also work with older iOS versions.

Comment: Thanks I forgot about UIAppearance

Comment: Sorry Scott, I cant get the UIAppearance to work on the UIDatePicker. Please see edited question.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer as it only suggests the use of UIAppearance, and not how to use it in this context.

Comment: No, you cannot use appearance to change `UIDatePicker`s graphics. Check my answer for more insight.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be quite difficult to change the way a `UIDatePicker` appears.

The example you provided, in my opinion, is a sophisticated customization of a simple `UIPickerView` with two columns and probably a simulated infinite scroll (as Apple does in the date picker, and it's quite simple to realize).

You can change little of the `UIDatePicker` through the `UIAppearance` proxy, as seen in this example:

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [UIDatePicker appearance];
picker.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];

UIView *view;
view = [UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], [UIDatePicker class], nil];
view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

UILabel *label = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], [UIDatePicker class], nil];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Using this piece of code at the start of the application (just try it) you can change the aspect of only a couple of the main components of the date picker.

Labels are **impossible** to customize (and this test code proves it); apparently they are changed in aspect every time you rotate a column, since they are put inside a custom `UITableView` controller.

To fully change these appearances you should probably work with private APIs from Apple, that will eventually result in your app being **rejected**.

If you just need a custom hour-minute picker (as shown in your screenshot), the full customization of appearance is reachable only extending the `UIPickerView` class or assigning an appropriate delegate to a `UIPickerView` instance.

Through the

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view;
```

method on the delegate you can make the single element of the picker view appear the way you want. Then you will have to appropriately handle the data source to make the two components of the picker virtually infinite.

Comment: I've looked at the UIApperance and still can't see how to change the text color of a UIDatePicker.  Does it support that?

Comment: As I said in the answer, labels are impossible to customize.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement one yourself using two UIScrollViews, one for hours and one for minutes.  You would just need to figure out the contentOffset of each scrollview when it has stopped moving, which off the top of my head would look like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
  if (!decelerate) {
    // get the offset here
  }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  // also get the offset here
}
```

Take the value of the content offset and translate it into the hour value and minute value, probably by dividing the y position of the content offset by the 24 or 60 respectively. You will need to make the custom artwork yourself.

Comment: Note that pickers have "infinite" scrolling: when you get to the end (say 59), you go back to the beginning. In reality, there really isn't an end and a beginning, but it appears so because of the numbers in there. This is definitely something to keep in mind when customizing UIScrollViews to mimic UIDatePicker behavior.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  I just downloaded the UNIQLO app to check and it would also require faking infinite scrolling (which would, of course, also complicate the math) and would also requiring some tricks using paging to get the scroll view to lock onto a particular position.

Comment: Without having thought this through completely, I think a UITableView may be an option. No hard math involved, just lazily keep adding cells as they are being scrolled to. Reusing cells would make for only a small performance hit, and using "scrollToRowAtIndexPath" would be useful for the position locking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

To change date picker color:

```
[datePickerView setValue:self.pickerLabelColor forKey:@"textColor"];
```

And to change font the only way I know is:

Create category `UIFont+System` and place this code inside

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
    + (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
    {
        return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
    }
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

This will set as well fonts in another places in your app (replacing system font by your font).

Answer (score -1):

You should go through the UICatalog by Apple. It has all the methods in which a UIDatePicker can be used including the custom date picker method . Study this link developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/ . Also they have implemented a standard switch and the navigation bar which is given in the latter.

Answer (score -1):

A combination of 2 `UITableViews` is the way to go.

`UITableView` is a subview of `UIScrollView`, so it handles the following event

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

}
```

and on getting the position, just scroll the table to the center using the following method

```
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.