# UIDatePicker show only picker like Sleep Cycle

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I would like to add a UIDatePickerModeTime picker, but the grey area around it seems so ugly to me. I am just wondering what's the best way of removing it? Is there some property I can set or any frame reset?

![image]

---

Well, I know one of the way to do it would be

Place the picker below a "background" image, which hides everything but the picker itself

Comment: wt u want i can't get it..please explain in deep :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case you can create your own custom date picker with `UIPickerView`.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844675/custom-ios-uidatepicker-using-uiappearance) might help you.