# Change UIPickerView pickerView:viewForRow: attributes based on a certain condition

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am trying to change the text color in `viewForRow` based on a certain condition. When I press a button the view changes to a different color but I would also like to change the colour of the text in the picker. I use 'viewForRow' because I have a custom view.

```
//adds subcategories to the wheel
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    if (!self.isBackgroundWhite)//Boolean that changes when the background changes
    {
        NSLog(@"Set white text");
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }else{

        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }



    if (row == 1) {
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[self.servicesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    }else{
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"     -%@",[self.servicesArray objectAtIndex:row] ];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFont size:16];
    }
        return label;
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Rich I was able to spot my problem, I just need to call `[self.pickerView reloadAllComponents]`;

Comment: Do you only want to change the text color and nothing else?

Comment: @Rich yup only text color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to change the text color just use the other delegate method [`pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSString *title;
    UIFont *font;
    if (row == 1) {
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[self.servicesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    } else{
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"     -%@",[self.servicesArray objectAtIndex:row] ];
        font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFont size:16];
    }

    UIColor *textColor;
    if (self.isBackgroundWhite) {
        textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Set white text");
        textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor, 
                                            NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};

    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attributes];
}
```

Also a note that you should call `[self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];` when changing `isBackgroundWhite`. I would do this by overriding the setter for `backgroundWhite` and when the boolean value changes reload the picker view.

EDIT:
There appears to be a 'bug' (intentional or not) in iOS 7 (works fine on iOS 6) with setting the `UIFont` on an `NSAttributedString` returned from the `pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:` method. So while the above works for the text color the font does not change. Luckily you can get around this with the code in the question. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945119/uipickerview-nsattributedstring-not-available-in-ios-7) for more info.

Comment: I need all the titles to be on aligned left not centre? Is there a way to do that here?

Comment: @Gman yep, you can use `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`, I'll add that.

Comment: @Gman check out [`NSMutableParagraphStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableParagraphStyle) for more options to set on the `paragraphStyle` object :)

Comment: Thanks Rich, its almost perfect accept the font does not change, it is @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" and size 18 for all

Comment: I got my original code working with [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents] :)

Comment: @Gman ah I did wonder what your exact problem was - your question was a bit vague :p glad you got it all working though! I'll check out the font issue :)

Comment: @Gman nevermind it appears to be a 'bug' (sort of) with iOS 7 when using the `UIFont`, I've updated the answer with a note to others!