# Make the text in a pickerView in Swift strikethrough

Tags: swift, uipickerview, strikethrough

I successfully added check numbers as text to a pickerView. But I wanted the text of the check numbers which had been used to be strikethrough. The code that can change a label's text to strikethrough does not work for items in a pickerView.  You get something like "1023 { this is a strikethrough }" in the pickerView.  Are there any fonts that have both strikethrough and normal characters? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following after seeing an example at http://makeapppie.com/tag/fonts-in-uipickerview/

This function simply had to be added to existing code. I discovered that every component had to be included or the components other than the check Number component would be blank.

```
 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {


    let myHueMax = 0.50
    let myPickerFontSize: CGFloat = 20.0
    print("component in lable == \(component)")

    var pickerLabel = view as! UILabel!
    var gHue = Double()


    if view == nil {  //if no label there yet
        pickerLabel = UILabel()
        //color the label's background

        var hue:CGFloat

        if component == payeeComponent  {

            hue = CGFloat(row)/CGFloat(payeesAlphbeticalArray.count)

        }else if component == categoryComponent {

            hue = CGFloat(row)/CGFloat(categoriesAlphbeticalArray.count)

        }else{

             hue = CGFloat(row)/CGFloat(checkNumbersAlphbeticalArray.count)

        }


        pickerLabel!.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        print("hue in label color == \(hue)")

        gHue = Double(hue)
    }

if component == payeeComponent  {



    let titleData = payeesAlphbeticalArray[row]

    var myTitle: NSAttributedString

    if ( gHue > myHueMax){
        myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
    }else{

        myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
    }

    pickerLabel!.attributedText = myTitle
    pickerLabel!.textAlignment = .Center


    return pickerLabel!



}else if component == categoryComponent{

    let titleData = categoriesAlphbeticalArray[row]

    var myTitle: NSAttributedString

    if ( gHue > myHueMax){
        myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
    }else{

        myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
    }


    pickerLabel!.attributedText = myTitle
    pickerLabel!.textAlignment = .Center


    return pickerLabel!



}else if component == checkNumberComponent {


    if checkNumbersAlphbeticalArray.isEmpty{

        return pickerLabel!

    }

    let titleData = checkNumbersAlphbeticalArray[row]

    var myTitle: NSAttributedString



    if isCheckNumberUsed(titleData){

        if ( gHue > myHueMax){
            myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(), NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 1])
        }else{

            myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor(), NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 1])
        }

    }else{

        if ( gHue > myHueMax){
            myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
        }else{

            myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: myPickerFontSize)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
        }
    }
    pickerLabel!.attributedText = myTitle
    pickerLabel!.textAlignment = .Center


    return pickerLabel!

    }

    return pickerLabel

}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but my code uses the same basic picker view api and is quite a bit more straightforward. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you need to use NSAttributedString objects for your picker views.

And [it looks like the only solution you might have available to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945119/uipickerview-nsattributedstring-not-available-in-ios-7) is to use the UIPickerViewDelegate method [`pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:).

If you implement that method, you'll be returning a UIView object into which you can have a UILabel which uses an attributed string.

If this were my problem, I'd probably do something like:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
              viewForRow row: Int,
            forComponent component: Int,
             reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    // create a mutable attributed string
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String here")
    // add strikethrough attribute to the whole string
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

    // set up a label
    let pickerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    pickerLabel.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    // and set the contents to the atributedString
    pickerLabel.attributedText = attributeString

    return pickerLabel
}
```

Comment: I did use the func you mention but used an example I found at [link](http://makeapppie.com/tag/fonts-in-uipickerview/) which worked perfectly with what I had.