# Why doesn't attributedTitleForRow get called with a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview, uipickerviewdelegate

As per the documentation, picker views prefer to use `attributedTitleForRow` over `titleForRow`. If the preferred returns nil, the picker view falls back to `titleForRow`.

I'm implementing both methods, and `attributedTitleForRow` never gets called. Even when `titleForRow` returns nil, and `attributedTitleForRow` returns an `NSAttributedString`, it doesn't get called. However, `titleForRow` always gets called.

Here's what I have:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return @"Hello";
}

- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                      forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"World"];
}
```

Comment: If you implement only pickerView(_:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:) , then is it called?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945119/uipickerview-nsattributedstring-not-available-in-ios-7

Comment: @user1000 Nope, still not called, but viewForRow is - looks like I'm going to have to go that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see that the `viewForRow` delegate method was also called. If this method is called, neither `titleForRow` nor `attributedTitleForRow` will run.