# How do I change the color of the text in a UIPickerView under iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uipickerview

I'm aware of the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView` method, but when using the `view` it passes in `reusingView:` how do I change it to use a different text color? If I use `view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` none of the views show up anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I change the font color of the datePicker in iOS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7)

Comment: @AaronBrager. Que Not a duplicate the link provided by u is asked after this que.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

There is a function in the delegate method that is more elegant:

**Objective-C:**

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *title = @"sample title";
    NSAttributedString *attString = 
        [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

    return attString;
}
```

If you want to change the selection bar colors as well, I found that I had to add 2 separate `UIViews` to the view containing the `UIPickerView`, spaced 35 pts apart for a picker height of 180.

**Swift 3:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let string = "myString"
    return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white])
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let string = "myString"
    return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
}
```

**Swift 4.2:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let string = "myString"
    return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
}
```

Remember when you use the method: You don't need to implement `titleForRowInComponent()` as it is never called when using `attributedTitleForRow()`.

Comment: By far this is the best answer as it also works for picker views with more than one component.

Answer (score 29):

Original post here: [can I change the font color of the datePicker in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7/19147577#19147577)

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d", row+1];
    return label;
}

// number Of Components
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// number Of Rows In Component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:   (NSInteger)component
{
    return 6;
}
```

Comment: This solution works fine for a pickerview containing a single component.  If you have more than 1, the labels will overlap from what I can see.

Answer (score 23):

1. Go to storyboard
2. Select PickerView
3. Go to Identity inspector (3rd tab)
4. Add User Defined Runtime Attribute
5. KeyPath = textColor
6. Type    = Color
7. Value   = [Color of you choice]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: it's work in a half, cus text is black but when u scroll it on picker he change to white

Comment: Works only if you scroll

Comment: Hi @chris-van-buskirk Check my add-on [_thePrettyPicker selectRow:prettyIndex inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Answer (score 7):

in Xamarin, override the UIPickerModelView method GetAttributedTitle

```
public override NSAttributedString GetAttributedTitle(UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
{
    // change text white
    string title = GetTitle (picker, row, component); // get current text from UIPickerViewModel::GetTitle
    NSAttributedString ns = new NSAttributedString (title, null, UIColor.White); // null = font, use current font
    return ns;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It works for me

```
pickerView.setValue(UIColor.yellow, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with a *pickerView* using two components. My solution is similar to above with a few modifications. Because I am using two components it is necessary to pull from two different arrays.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];

    //WithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 60)];

    if(component == 0)
    {
        label.text = [countryArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        label.text = [cityArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return label;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 (Update to the accepted answer)

```
extension MyViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate{
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        return NSAttributedString(string: "your-title-goes-here", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
        UILabel* pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 37)];
        pickerLabel.text = @"text";
        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return pickerLabel;
}
```