# Change Color of UIPickerView Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView and I would like to change the color of the text to white according to the method shown in this stack overflow question: [How do I change the color of the text in a UIPickerView under iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232817/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-a-uipickerview-under-ios-7) .

However, the code that I typed does not seem to work. Can someone please tell me why?

I have the following method in my ViewController.m

```
- (NSAttributedString *)changePickerColor:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component :(NSString*)title
 {
     NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

     return attString;
}
```

And in my viewDidLoad I this code:

```
self.instruments = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Baritone",@"Trumpet",@"French Horn",@"Tuba", nil];
for (int i = 0; i < self.instruments.count; i++) {
    [self changePickerColor:self.pickerView attributedTitleForRow:i forComponent:0 :self.instruments[i]];
}
```

I am not receiving any error messages, the code simply just does not work. 
Please Help, Thank You.

Comment: `pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:` is the delegate method defined by the protocol -- it must be named exactly like that (like in the answer you linked to).  Additionally, you're not supposed to call it yourself -- the picker view will call it (as long as it's named right).

Comment: Try like this,  

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7

This may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Alternatively you may use the below delegate also and define a UILabel to set your preferred color for the text

  ```
  – pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
  ```