# How to Change Font style in uipickerview title text?

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview

Change Font style  in uipickerview title text.
i want to change only selected title row  font style is bold and other title text is normal font.change title font style i want to font style is Helvetica Neue Bold.

Comment: Thank you sir,but in this link all pickerview text is bold i want to only selected title text font change

Comment: check with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19825249/5362916

Comment: Font style will be  change  NSAttributedString

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
   if(row == yourSelectedIndex)//to set as bold
   {
    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView)
    {
       tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
       [tView setFont:[UIFont boldFontWithSize:14"]];
    }
    tView.text=@"your text values";
   return tView;
  }
}
```