# How do I change the font color of UIPickerView and UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I have a `viewController` with a `UIPickerView` and a `UIDatePicker` as shown in the screenshot from my `storyboard` as below. 
[image: The screenshot from my storyboard]
I tried adding runtime attribute as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520350/3921490). But following it only changed the font color of the initially highlighted text. 
I want to change the color of text in my both pickerView and datePicker to white. I am unaware of how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to write this line to change date picker text color,

```
 self.datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

It will change textcolor of `UIDatePicker`

And For `PickeView`, You have to set attributed string like,

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    return NSAttributedString(string: "Your Text", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blue])
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It's pathetic that Apple won't just provide a simple ```setTextColor``` method for this. I can't believe they think it's acceptable to only have black font....

Answer (score 2):

These two lines saved the day for me.

```
    NepaliDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
    EnglishDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "viewForRow" delegate method for "UIPickerView"

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
     // Your custom view with custom font here
}
```

For UIDatePicker you can't change font but you can use this code to change textColor.

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
datePicker.datePickerMode = .CountDownTimer
datePicker.datePickerMode = .DateAndTime
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use attributedTitleForRow delegate method of picker view to change colors. refer this link [How do I change the color of the text in a UIPickerView under iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232817/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-a-uipickerview-under-ios-7). You can also use viewForRow delegate method and add a Custom UILabel as the view.

Comment: This is the same question I posted in my question as reference.

Comment: Ok. did u got your answers? @amagain