# Avoid UIDatePicker transparency in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uidatepicker

i just upgraded my app to iOS7 and found that date picker is transparent.
It looks like I can see everything which is behind the date picker. 
How can I avoid this?

I tried to place date picker in another view. But still, its transparent.
How can I avoid transparency of `UIDatePicker`? I've tried [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UQIG.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UQIG.png): [can I change the font color of the datePicker in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7) but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Edit : I've added a `UIDatePicker` to a view named `whiteborderview`.

```
whiteborderview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

whiteborderview.alpha = 1.0;

[whiteborderview addSubview:dtPkrStart]
```

and I got output like this

[image: transparent datepicker]

but still its transparent.

**Edit2**

I used this code and now its looking better than previous one

```
[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], [UIDatePicker class], nil].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];

dtPkrStart.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

The date picker appearence changed like this [image: date picker new look]

Answer (score 55):

Just change background color of your date picker

```
datepicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourcolor];
```

Comment: This works fine for me:  datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.95];  I used 0.95 here so there's still a little bit of transparency, but 1.0 works fine if you want it completely opaque.

Comment: any idea why it doesn't work from the interface builder?

Comment: @codrut because Apple loves to poke at us iOS developers here and there.

Comment: Looks like a bug... Still here in Xcode 7.1; cannot change background color from interface builder (stays transparent whatever the setting), but works fine from code: `_datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Answer (score 6):

you can add a uiview with any color behind the uidatepicker.
it will work for you.

Comment: i've placed the datepicker in a view which is not transprent and applied white color for that.But the same view is placed over a transparent view(thats my requirment).But the end result is datepicker is still transparent. :(

Comment: The datepicker will remain transparent. but the view that is in background of datepicker will remove the transparency of the datepicker. its just like, if you put any color sheet behind a transparent glass

Comment: i've done the same .but still i can see through datepicker.everything behind the view is visible. alpha content of view is set to 2:(

Comment: alpha should be between 0-1. in your case it should be 1

Comment: i've added screen shot

Comment: thanks, please show me the code or nib file that how you added the background view.i think the background view is transparent

Comment: its not resolved yet.i've replaced the white bordered view with a imageview and applied a white image.but still its transparent. the background transparent view is set like this
transprnt.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];

transprnt.alpha = 0.800000011920929;

[transprnt addSubview:whiteborderview];

Comment: yes, that is causing all the subview transparent. for this make this view's alpha as 1. problem will be solved.

Comment: i cant do that.the view should be transparent.its a requirment.i've specified dat earlier and yes its working fine when transparency is set to 1 . btw do u knw how to change the font color of datepicker?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7 check this link. and for transparent view. you should add view1 with transparency on parent view. then add another view on parent without transparency which have uipickerview.it will work for you . and please make answer as correct if it works

Comment: no it didnt work. i've mentioned the same link in my question too.while debugging its got getting into that function. what should i do?:(

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], [UIDatePicker class], nil].backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0];
pickerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
anotherView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];//Another view on which you subview picker
```

Comment: To avoid transparency, make subview picker view to another view and use following code: