# Avoid transparency in iOS7 picker on webpage

Tags: html, ios, ios7, transparency, picker

How can I avoid transparency in the iOS 7 picker from the web page (not app)? So far I have only found this ([Avoid UIDatePicker transparency in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264325/avoid-datepicker-transparency-in-ios7)) but it works only for app.

Comment: u mean on web view element of ios??

Comment: @NSS I'm not sure what you mean, but I mean from a webpage's perspective not from an app perspective

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388814/date-picker-for-iphone-web-application This might help you..

Comment: @P.J sorry, that's not what I mean. I want to avoid background transparency in the new picker in iOS7

Comment: @Angela The above link does have other custom controls and solution to modify background. Also, there is a trick, try to add picker by setting some background color and something like that... Something on background which removes transparency.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this using standard HTML, JavaScript or CSS means.

Comment: But what about events? does Safari trigger some kind of event when the picker is initiated? If so I can still salvage it by creating a temporary overlay of some sort

Comment: @Angela: I don't think that u will get allowed to play with Apple's in-built app's events as u r thinking!

Comment: @NSS This is a web page; why do you think Apple has any say in it? If indeed there is some event thrown and possible to listen to, it would be possible to just add a view where the picker should be.