# Change dark background for datepicker on ios 7

Tags: ios, cordova, background

I'm using phonegap to develop a mobile app. The datepicker on ios 7 gets a dark background (see image). How do I change the color of the background?

See image examples at: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/dark_background_for_datepicker_on_ios_7

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I change the font color of the datePicker in iOS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7)

Comment: you'll find answers about background color change too in the above post

Comment: Duplicate? Im asking how to change the background color not the font color.

Comment: have you checked that post and the answers? Sulthan probably has an answer there. And others have answers for changing background color too...

Comment: Yep that's a solution but I don't think it's the solution when you are developing with the Cordova / Phonegap framework.

Comment: The main idea behind Cordova / Phonegap is to make apps cross platform compatible. But an iOS7 style datepicker will only work in iOS7. I used phonegap for app development but there were couple of specific things I had to go and change in Objective-C, so I don't see any problem using that solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same exact issue, and found the answer!  If you are building the Cordova/PhoneGap project locally on your machine and are NOT using PhoneGapBuild, the fix is really simple.

In Xcode, open your project, expand the yellow Classes folder and open **MainViewController.m** file.

On **line 107** of **MainViewController.m** you see the line below :

```
theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Change it to :

```
theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Alternatively, if you are using PhoneGapBuild and don't have access to modify the iOS project files, someone developed a cordova/phonegap plugin to fix this issue.  It can be found below.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/iOSWebViewColor-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the jquery mobile datepicker..

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/