# UIPickerView Text Color Change In This Implementation

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview

I had an app about a year and half ago I was fooling with that I decided to come back to it.  When I left it the pickerview was visible and worked.  Now it still works but the text color is black along with the background.  How can I get the text color different with these functions?

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if (component == SIZE)
        return [arraySize count];
    if (component == MEASURE)
        return [arrayMeasure count];
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (component == SIZE)
        return [arraySize objectAtIndex:row];
    if (component == MEASURE)
        return [arrayMeasure objectAtIndex:row];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method may be help you.

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSAttributedString *attString  = nil;
    NSString *title = @"";

    if (component == SIZE)
        title = [arraySize objectAtIndex:row];
    if (component == MEASURE)
        title = [arrayMeasure objectAtIndex:row];
   attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]}];

   return attString;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the color for each label in the picker. See this thread for the answer: [can I change the font color of the datePicker in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the title use:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                      forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

This lets you provide an attributed string for the title.

#### Example

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView  
             attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
                      forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your title"              
                                           attributes:@
    {
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]
    }];
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it just changes all my pickerview selections to "Your Title".

Comment: `Your title` is just an example. Replace it with desired string value based on row index.