# Change UIDatePicker font color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, colors, uidatepicker

All I want to do is change the font color of the UIDatePicker. I've researched other questions but they're all involving changing other properties and customizing the entire look. All I want to do is just change the font color from black to white. I find it hard to believe that I can't do such a seemingly simple task. And why wouldn't the tint color affect it? Does it even do anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I change the font color of the datePicker in iOS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7)

Comment: In question above I found my solution.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

All I need (on iOS 8.x and 9.0) is this one line to change the font color:

```
        [my_date_picker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
```

No subclassing or invoking of private APIs...

---

Note: today's current date will still be highlighted (in newer iOS versions). You can get around this by using the following code:

```
if ([my_date_picker respondsToSelector:sel_registerName("setHighlightsToday:")]) {

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"

        [my_date_picker performSelector:@selector(setHighlightsToday:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

}
```

Comment: I tried, but the parts of today's date are in the wrong color, the 10 and the October are black, I don't mind the year being in the wrong color but the other 2 feels weird

Comment: @vshade, do you have a code snippet posted somewhere? happy to take a look...things still are working for me...

Comment: same thing here with "Today", at least.

Comment: This changes all text to white EXCEPT the current date (August 2 2015, for example would all be black).

Comment: For current date `[my_date_picker performSelector:@selector(setHighlightsToday:) withObject:NO];`

Comment: Is it possible to set the font as well?

Comment: @NikKov That can throw a warning in the newest version and can possibly break in future versions so I'm editing code into the answer to reflect how to handle both of the cases I just mentioned when using your method. Thanks!

Comment: Code Works perfect. Thanks for help

Comment: I had to use this:  [_datePickerOutlet setValue:UIColor.blackColor forKey:@"textColor"];  #ObjectiveC

Comment: Figured out the default style changed, to get the wheel style back picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels is needed, then this solution continues to work

Comment: setHighlightsToday is no longer available on iOS 14

Comment: no longer works for iOS14 - The `picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels` does work - but what about color change ???

Answer (score 25):

One other alternative to [@Jeremiah answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33156094/2618071) is to define those values in  Interface Builder.
I prefer this one because there is no code to add in your ViewController.

Click into your DatePicker view and customise it from the Attribute inspector as in the screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Works for Swift 2, 3, 4 and probably for Swift < 2. (not tested)

Comment: Unfortunately this only colors the word "Today"... and nothing else. And if you set the highlightsToday off, the textColor has no effect. This is in Xcode 11.

Comment: In Xcode 14.2 highlightsToday has no effect, textColor works. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

As of Swift 2.1:

```
picker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
picker.sendAction("setHighlightsToday:", to: nil, forEvent: nil)
let date = NSDate()
picker.setDate(date, animated: false)
```

Instead of "today" you will see the current day,

Comment: `setHighlightsToday` causes a warning, `No method declared with Objective-C selector 'setHighlightsToday:'`

Comment: Swift 3: picker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
            picker.sendAction(Selector(("setHighlightsToday:")), to: nil, for: nil)

Comment: In Xcode12/Swift 5.3 `…Selector(("setHighlightsToday:"))…` needs to drop `:` to be `…Selector(("setHighlightsToday"))…` to not have a runtime crash.

Answer (score 20):

Next solution comes from "arturgrigor" and it works great in my apps, just copy it, paste it in viewDidLoad method, and enjoy it :

```
[my_datePicker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"textColor"];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString( @"setHighlightsToday:" );
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature :
                           [UIDatePicker 
                            instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
BOOL no = NO;
[invocation setSelector:selector];
[invocation setArgument:&no atIndex:2];
[invocation invokeWithTarget:my_datePicker];
```

Comment: what about changing the font ?

Comment: You should be careful with this. this invokes an private api of apple and apple might reject your app for it!

Comment: @SarenInden, my apps Acces-o and Acces-o School use it, don't worry!

Answer (score 9):

According to [`Apple's UIKit User Interface Catalog`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker), developers are not allowed to customize date pickers.

I've seen other StackOverflow answers for similar questions that [suggest making a fake UIDatePicker using UIPickerView and customizing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844675/custom-ios-uidatepicker-using-uiappearance).

[I also found an open source date picker on GitHub (at https://github.com/mwermuth/MWDatePicker )](https://github.com/mwermuth/MWDatePicker) that might help a bit. It allows for different background and selector styles, but not a different font or font attributes.... yet.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I checked out the MWDatePicker, but it looks like it hasn't been updated for iOS 7 yet. It's just a blank picker when I run the sample project. I've settled for making a simulating a UIDatePicker by customizing a UIPicker. Thanks for the help. It's still very surprising Apple does not allow the customization of a date picker. I wonder why that is?

Comment: I see there's a [pull request](https://github.com/mwermuth/MWDatePicker/pulls) open to modernize MWDatePicker to iOS 7. It would be good if the owner merged it, but at least you can grab it and make use of it.

Answer (score 6):

To change UIDatePicker text color use:

```
    // MARK: - Helping content 

    private enum DatePickerProperties: String {
        case TextColor = "textColor"
        case HighlightsToday = "highlightsToday"
    }

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    // MARK: - Lifecicle

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: DatePickerProperties.TextColor.rawValue)
        self.datePicker.setValue(false, forKey: DatePickerProperties.HighlightsToday.rawValue)
    }
```

It works like a charm with xCode 7.3 and Swift 2.3.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon a surprisingly clean solution using `UIAppearance`, without using any KVC, swizzling, or otherwise private API. I found that attempting to set the `textColor` via `UIAppearance` for any `UILabel` within a `UIDatePicker` had no affect, but a custom appearance property that simply called the regular `textColor` setter worked just fine.

```
// Implement a custom appearance property via a UILabel category
@interface UILabel (PickerLabelTextColor)

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor * textColorWorkaround UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

@end

@implementation UILabel (PickerLabelTextColor)

- (UIColor *)textColorWorkaround {
    return self.textColor;
}

- (void)setTextColorWorkaround:(UIColor *)textColor {
    self.textColor = textColor;
}

@end
```

And then use as follows:

```
UILabel *pickerLabelProxy = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[UIDatePicker.class]];
pickerLabelProxy.textColorWorkaround = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
```

### Swift Version

UILabel extension:

```
extension UILabel {
    @objc dynamic var textColorWorkaround: UIColor? {
        get {
            return textColor
        }
        set {
            textColor = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Appearance proxy use:

```
let pickerLabelProxy = UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDatePicker.self])
pickerLabelProxy.textColorWorkaround = UIColor.lightGray
```

Comment: Can you provide a swift version of this solution please

Comment: @keegan3d Added! It compiles and should be functionally equivalent, but I haven't used this strategy recently. Let us know if it still works!

Comment: I'm trying it now in iOS 16.5.1 and it works really well when the component first appears, but changing the highlighted digits, and then moving to another, the previously highlighted one reverts to white, same thing with panning screens at a time or rolling the wheels.

Comment: It still works in August, 2023

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wants the swift solution, I placed the following in viewDidLoad:

```
    birthdayDatePicker.setValue(DesignHelper.getOffWhiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
    birthdayDatePicker.performSelector("setHighlightsToday:", withObject:DesignHelper.getOffWhiteColor())
```

Comment: great!, any solution for Swift < 2? performSelector isn't available in 1.2

Comment: anyway to remove the warning in xcode 7.3 - No method declared with Objective-C selector "setHighlightsToday:" ?

Comment: I haven't found one. I've confirmed it works and is still needed. If anyone has a way to do this without getting a warning that would be awesome!

Comment: To suppress warnings check out this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194666/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode

Answer (score 4):

For Xamarin developers:

```
DatePicker.SetValueForKey(UIColor.White, new NSString("textColor"));
DatePicker.SetValueForKey(FromObject(false), new NSString("highlightsToday"));
```

It´s working like a charm.
Tested in iOS 9 and 10

Answer (score 3):

You can also add this as an IBDesignable if you want to configure this within InterFace Builder.

```
    import UIKit

@IBDesignable
extension UIDatePicker {
    @IBInspectable var textLabelColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return self.valueForKey("textColor") as? UIColor
        }
        set {
            self.setValue(newValue, forKey: "textColor")
            self.performSelector("setHighlightsToday:", withObject:newValue) //For some reason this line makes the highlighted text appear the same color but can not be changed from textColor. 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This subclass of UIDatePicker works for iOS 7. Its not pretty but gets the job done.

```
#define kNotification_UIView_didAddSubview @"kNotification_UIView_didAddSubview"
@implementation UIView (addSubview)

-(void) didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification_UIView_didAddSubview object:self];
}
@end


@interface DatePicker ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* textColor;
@end

@implementation DatePicker

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self){
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self){
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setup{
    self.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(subviewsUpdated:) name:kNotification_UIView_didAddSubview object:nil];
}

-(void) dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void) updateLabels:(UIView*) view{
    for (UILabel* label in view.subviews){
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            label.textColor = self.textColor;
        }else{
            [self updateLabels:label];
        }
    }
}

-(BOOL) isSubview:(UIView*) view{
    if (view == nil){
        return NO;
    }
    if (view.superview == self){
        return YES;
    }
    return [self isSubview:view.superview];
}

-(void) subviewsUpdated:(NSNotification*) notification{
    if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIPickerTableView")] && [self isSubview:notification.object]){
        [self updateLabels:notification.object];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[date_picker setValue:textColor forKey:@"textColor"];
[date_picker performSelector:@selector(setHighlightsToday:) withObject:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Runtime Attribute named "textColor" from Storyboard as shown in following image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to @Jeremiah answer, you can use this:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.redColor(), forKey: "textColor")
datePicker.sendAction("setHighlightsToday:", to: nil, forEvent: nil)
datePicker.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0), animated: false)
```

it will remove Today (you will see current date), but it will be with right color.

Possible troubles:
if you change color dynamically, I didn't find a way to reload date picker. So, the user will see previous color and only after scroll, color will changed to a new one. -> Solved, by last string. Looks like Voodoo, but it works...

This answer suitable for Swift 2.1

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work until textColor was set inside layoutSubviews()

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    datePicker.backgroundColor = .black
    datePicker.setValue(.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `datePicker.tintColor = .red` or any other color you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
[my_date_picker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
```

it seems don't work on ios 13 or later, you can set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property for UIDatePicker to determin it shows white color or black.