# How to set green color in UIDatePicker selected row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

How can I set a green color in `UIDatePicker`'s selected row. I had searched and put some kind of code like below,

The first one is:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class],[UIDatePicker class], nil];
label.font = HELVETICA_NEUE(24);
label.textColor = GREEN_COLOR;
```

Here, the green color is only set on the date and month, but not the year. And the other non-selected dates in the picker should still show up black.

I just want the selected row to be green.

Next, I followed the Aron post in below link:

[can I change the font color of the datePicker in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807940/can-i-change-the-font-color-of-the-datepicker-in-ios7)

Then I create the `UILabel` + `UIDatePickerLabel` class file in my project.

ALL the dates in the `UIDatePicker` showed up green, and I need only the selected row to be green. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: do u need to change the font color or selection indicator color?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *overIndicoloe = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 280, 44)];
overIndicoloe.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
overIndicoloe.alpha = 0.5f;
[yourDatePicker addSubview: overIndicoloe];
```

Comment: u need to change the font color or selection indicator of the row color

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I need to change selected row text color but your code only display the green background color of the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

if u need to change the text color

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d", row];
    return label;    
    }
```

Comment: Would be fine, if `UIDatePicker` would be an element of `UIPickerView`. better see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21084227/883799 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/20875372/883799 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also change just the **selection indicator's background** color now.
Just *add a UIView* above the selection indicator, set it's *alpha value low*(depends on you, I like my overlay to look transparent), *give it a background color* and you are good to go.

Consider this,

```
var overlayOnPicker:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(1, 68, mypicker.frame.width, 26))
// Adds a layer on the selection indicator
```

And do put the **CGRect's X value=1**
    (remember, it's a frame, so it will be placed according to the superview's coordinate system)

```
overlayOnPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
overlayOnPicker.alpha = 0.2
myDatePicker.addSubview(overlayOnPicker)
//You have to add the overlayOnPicker view as a subview to the Date Picker.
//myDatePicker is the UIDatePicker that I declared earlier in my code
```

Still figuring out how to change text's color in date picker