# Change UIDatePicker text color

Tags: string, swift, uidatepicker, nsattributedstring

How do I change the color of the text in the UIDatePicker View. Should I use attributed strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's UIKit User Interface Catalog, developers are not allowed to customise date pickers. It has been said already around...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker-SW3

Life's tough!

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you can:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246053/3376758

I'm not 100% sure if its allowed or not but it works like a charm.