# Set text color for UIDatePicker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've been having some trouble trying to set the `UIDatePicker` font and color, but colour of `label` today in `datePicker` is not changed. Everything else in my app was fairly straightforward to adjust, except this. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
func updatedatePicker(){                
    DatePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
    DatePicker.setValue(1, forKeyPath: "alpha")    
}
```

In `viewDidLoad()` :-

```
DatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.updatedatePicker), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change UIDatePicker font color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875054/change-uidatepicker-font-color)

Comment: Here is an elegant way to do this using extensions
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633690/3882644

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have face the same issue so i have try something like this, Changing the `datePickerMode` to something else, it will re-draw with the newly set `textColor`, also instead of setting `textColor` in `updatedatePicker` function set this also in `viewDidLoad` like this.

Answer updated to latest Swift 4

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime //Set here that mode you want.
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedDate), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Comment: In iOS 14-16 this doesn't work. See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711760

Answer (score 1):

If your solution didn't work you can try to add the ext color through inspector like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change UIDatePicker text color use:

```
    // MARK: - Helping content 

    private enum DatePickerProperties: String {
        case TextColor = "textColor"
        case HighlightsToday = "highlightsToday"
    }

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    // MARK: - Lifecicle

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: DatePickerProperties.TextColor.rawValue)
        self.datePicker.setValue(false, forKey: DatePickerProperties.HighlightsToday.rawValue)
    }
```

It works like a charm with xCode 7.3 and Swift 2.3.