# How do I change the color a UIDatePicker in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, datetimepicker, swift5

How would I go about changing the color of the text in a UIDatePicker? I would prefer not to use UIPickerView as I don't want to deal with the implementation of the date/time aspect of it, however, if there exists a prewritten implementation of the equivalent of a UIDatePicker as a UIPickerView, I would be open to it.

Note, I am using Swift 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set text color for UIDatePicker in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972197/set-text-color-for-uidatepicker-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Still Works, Swift 5 Update
> ```

```
  datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

This works for me.

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
```