# iOS 9.2 UIDatePicker component currently selected component row's text color not changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uidatepicker

I can not change the font size of each component rows and currently selected component row's text color of UIDatePicker.

In ViewDidLoad, my code is :

```
    self.dPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.dPicker setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
```

Is is limited by Apple?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any API for change apperiance of `UIDatePicker`

then also if you want to do like that, you can do using swift:

See this for customizable implementation of `UIDatePicker`

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/PIDatePicker

If you want to change the color of selected row, then u need to change the font color or selection indicator of the row color

```
UIView *abc = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 280, 44)];
abc.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

abc.alpha = 0.5f;
[yourDatePicker addSubview: abc];
```

Try this for color:

```
yourDatePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
yourDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.blueColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
yourDatePicker.setValue(0.8, forKeyPath: "alpha")
```

Comment: Thanks.  Suraj Sukale

Comment: glad.. i could help

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker-SW3), we are not allowed to customize date pickers.

I suggest you look at other StackOverflow answers for similar questions that suggest making [a fake UIDatePicker using UIPickerView and customizing that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844675/custom-ios-uidatepicker-using-uiappearance)

Answer (score 0):

@jamshed You don't need create a subview and add it to UIDatePicker.
If you want to change highlight text color of UIDatePicker, you can use this code:

`[self.datePicker setValue:@(false) forKey:@"highlightsToday"];`